# Turn off cache in Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, caching

I keep receive this error log in my server.

```
2018-04-05 13:51:28
[66.249.93.22][-][-][warning][yii\log\Dispatcher::dispatch] Unable to
send log via yii\log\FileTarget: Exception (Invalid Configuration)
'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to append to
log file: /var/www/html/translate/runtime/logs/all-levels.log'

in /var/www/html/translate/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/FileTarget.php:108

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/translate/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php(124):
yii\log\FileTarget->export()
#1
/var/www/html/translate/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Dispatcher.php(188):
yii\log\Target->collect(Array, true)
#2 /var/www/html/translate/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Logger.php(177):
yii\log\Dispatcher->dispatch(Array, true)
#3 [internal function]: yii\log\Logger->flush(true)
#4 {main}
```

It is a nginx server on Ubuntu. Shall I turn off cache in nginx?

Comment: "_'Unable to append to
log file: /var/www/html/translate/runtime/logs/all-levels.log'_" sounds like wrong permissions or non-existant file for me. Why do you want to turn off cache?

Comment: I tried chmod 777 for that folder and still the same result.